# contactform7 remove tags with "wpcf7_autop false" from functions.php

Tags: functions, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

i want to remove those `<p>` and `<br/>` tags from my contactform7 forms. now they have this wpcf7_autop which can be set to false when inserting:

```
define('WPCF7_AUTOP', false);
```

to wp-config.php

**The problem is:**
I need this setting to be attached with my theme, so is it possible to some how do it through the functions.php file?

Comment: Plugin loaded before theme. It isn't possible!

Comment: so how come i'm able to disable the plugins css and javascript from loading through the functions.php ?

Comment: CSS, JS are hooked on `wp_enqueue_scripts` which you can remove. But it is PHP constant. How about defining DB details in `functions.php` sounds wired right ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can try minify html from the contact form 7
- To completely disable the wpautop filter, you can use:

  ```
  remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
  ```

Answer (score 9):

If you have already upgraded CF7 to [version 5.0](https://contactform7.com/2018/01/31/contact-form-7-50/) or higher, then you can use the new hook:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_autop_or_not', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to get ride of autop (automatic `<p>` tag) and line breaking tag (`<br>` tag).

```
<?php
// Remove auto p from Contact Form 7 shortcode output
add_filter('wpcf7_autop_or_not', 'wpcf7_autop_return_false');
function wpcf7_autop_return_false() {
    return false;
}
```

Add this code to your theme's `function.php` file.